# PostgreSQL: How to use more than one CPU?

Tags: postgresql, pgrouting, transportation, performance

I'm creating a real time traffic application. I read the AVL car data from a web service and insert the records in a PostgreSQL table.

Then a trigger calculates the closest link and if there is a previous position for the same car, I calculate the route to get the distance travelled in that time frame, then I get the average speed for that route.

The thing is, I get around 3000 points each 5 minutes, so I need to process ~600 records per minute (10 each second). I'm very close to those numbers because I filter the road network before calling the routing function and the routes are very small.

I understand PostgreSQL doesn't support multiple threads in one connection but supports multiple connections, so could use the other CPU cores.

I can make a different table for each State (25), but how can I partition the problem so each trigger creates a new connection and usse more CPU cores instead of only one?

Comment: What you're asking is a bit unclear to me, but PostgreSQL automatically utilizes multiple cores based on the number of connections. Are you asking how to create multiple connections?

Answer (score 9):

See [this help document](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/ecpg-connect.html) for creating multiple connections.

This simple code will create multiple connections:

```
    EXEC SQL CONNECT TO testdb1 AS con1 USER testuser;
    EXEC SQL CONNECT TO testdb2 AS con2 USER testuser;
    EXEC SQL CONNECT TO testdb3 AS con3 USER testuser;
```

You can then choose a connection to use:

```
    EXEC SQL AT connection-name SELECT ...;
```

Finally you need to disconnect all of your connections:

```
    EXEC SQL DISCONNECT ALL;
```

This code will automatically make use of multiple threads and doesn't require you to create redundancies, such as duplicate tables.

Comment: And raise Shared Mem configuration value so high that all shared data (route networks) is in memory

Comment: Yes, multiple connections is what i'm looking for. I will try it and let you know.